# How to swap words in a parentheses "()" using regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, swap

How can I replace the words like:

```
something(name_one,name_two).
```

into

```
something(name_two,name_one).
```

I've tried something like `^(.+),(.+)$` and replace with `\2,\1`, but not success and it turns out to be like this:

```
name_two).,something(name_one
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to exclude from the capturing groups what you don't want to be swapped.

Replace

```
something\((.+),(.+)\)
```

with

```
something(\2,\1)
```

([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/25R4Xm/1))

Or

Replace

```
\((.+),(.+)\)
```

with

```
(\2,\1)
```

([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/UIrUa0/1))

Please notice that `\(` and `\)` are escaped parentheses, so they will match *literally* an open parenthesis and a closed one.

Answer (score 0):

Find what: `\(\K(.*),(.*)(?=\))`
Replace with: `$2,$1`